# Double Clicking windows in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, themes, 18.04, resize, doubleclick

Double-clicking windows title changes the shape of the window to only the windows title width and I cannot resize from there. [image]

For example when emacs application is bigger if I double click on that black header then the window changes to the one shown in the picture. Is it a feature or a bug? Its the same issue with all other themes

Comment: I think you can change what double clicking on the title bar does in the settings..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also install Gnome-Tweak-Tool and on the Left Panel you have the "Windows" Panel, where can you change the Title Bar Actions.

Check also: https://linuxhint.com/best-gnome-tweaks-gnome-tweak-tool/